# How to override class behaviour in a JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to create JUnit tests for a method in class A, that creates an instance of class B. Since, I want to isolate the method's behaviour, I would like to override B's methods in my test suite for A with simpler ones, that would work for the purposes of testing A.

I have tried doing so using Mockito's Spy, however as I understand it only allows to return a static value upon a method call, however I need to replace complex external logic with simpler one, while taking into account the parameters passed.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Sounds like you have to learn about mocking

Comment: You need to create a mock instance of B, and then return different responses to the calls on B, depending on what scenario you want to test: https://javacodehouse.com/blog/mockito-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got you right the code example might look like this

```
public class A {
    public T doSth(){
       String result = new B().callMethod();
    }
}
```

To make A more testable the following approach might be useful if you're able to modify the source code.

```
public class A {
    private MyInterface b;
    public A(MyInterface b){
      this.b = b;
    }
    public T doSth(){
       String result = b.callMethod();
    }
}
```

1. Introduce an interface that class B is implementing
2. make sure class A does only depend on the interface by injecting an instance of B via setter method or constructor
3. now you can use a mocking framework like Mockito to configure result values or just use a test stub (inner class that implements the interface and the logic you like)

Cheers